# Iterating through vector: replacement has length zero

Tags: r, vector, zoo

I am trying to iterate through a vector and edit a new one however I keep getting the error replacement has length zero. The portion where the error occurs is here:

```
NewPos1 = rep(NROW(sig_decision))
for( i in 2:length(NewPos)) {
 NewPos1[i] = ifelse( NewPos[i] == 0 & NewPos[i-1] == 1 & ind1[i] > 0 , 1, 
      ifelse(NewPos[i] ==0 & NewPos[i-1] == -1 & ind1[i] < 0  , -1,0))
}
```

Ok to be more specific

Where am I going wrong?

Edit: I should be more specific ind1 is a numeric vector. The reason why I want a loop is so that starting with the 2nd element in NewPos1([NewPos[1]) if the previous element of NewPos(NewPos[1]) is 1 and ind1[2] > 0 then I want NewPos1[2] to be one and so forth iterating through the entire vector so that if ind1[3] is >0 then NewPos1[3] is also 1

Comment: I don't know what any of those variables are.

Comment: What is `sig_decision` ?  What is `NewPos` , as you've only defined `NewPos1` .   In the meantime, check out `switch` rather than nesting dozens of `if else` elements.

Comment: see http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 on reproducibility ...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is very likely to lie with `ind1` (since you haven't told us what that is).  I'm guessing that (if `ind1` is really a numeric vector the same length as `NewPos`) this is a more efficient solution to your problem:

```
v <- NewPos[-1]  ## elements 2:n
ind2 <- ind1[-1] ## elements 2:n
vlag1 <- NewPos[-length(NewPos)] ## elements 1:(n-1)
NewPos1 <- ifelse(v==0 & vlag1==1 & ind2>0, 1,
               ifelse(v==0 & vlag==-1 & ind2<0, -1, 0))
```

As @CarlWitthoft points out, `switch` can sometimes be useful, but I don't think that two nested `ifelse` statements is excessive.